# netbeans collapse comment block

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I've been using netbeans for 1 week, and it's a very powerful environment, but I found a little leak. I'm coding in javascript, and I can't collapse scriptdoc code (or nn general comments block).
It works only on first comment block, then only function could be collapsed (see the attached immage)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Netbeans IDE, navigate to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Editor`.

Under the `General` tab, the `Tags and Other Code Blocks` option lets you collapse your comment blocks.

[image: Netbeans setting: Collapsing Code Blocks]